# Elasticsearch 2.0: _id is not configurable

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

ES 2.0 is just released. Out of curiosity, I tested my mapping file that has been working for ES 1.7.3 against ES 2.0. I got the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "_id is not configurable"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "mapping [mydoctype]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "_id is not configurable"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Basically, this error complains about my mapping file which contains the following:

```
"mydoctype": {
    "_id" : {
        "path" : "id"
    },
```

Just did google and failed to find a way to set doc _id to the actual identifier of indexed document in ES 2.0.  How can I do that?

Thanks for any pointer and input!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [announcing blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/great-mapping-refactoring#meta-fields), you now need to set the value explicitly in your indexing query, i.e.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/YOUR_ID -d '{...}'
                                                  ^
                                                  |
                                          set your id here
```

Or in your `_bulk` query:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/_bulk -d '
{"index": {"_id": "YOUR_ID"}}
{...}                 ^
'                     |
              set your id here
```